# Visual studio not showing references

Tags: visual-studio

I have a problem in my visual studio 2012, the références are not being show
The error is "An error occurred trying to load to page.Unable to cast COM object of type 'System._ComObject'to interface type 'EnvDTE.ProjectItemsEvents'.

I have trying changing the options but nothing changer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case, a screenshot of the error would be helpful. I have no clue where you see that error.

Comment: Sounds like your VS2012 install collapsed into a pile of rubble.  Re-install or upgrade to  get ahead.  [Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d80cf28f-2a2f-4dc2-9b82-d84790ca29b4/error-on-references-page-of-projects-properties?forum=vbide)